# Forward new Google chat requests to the delegation master account

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

I have an old Gmail account that is bound to my Android cellphone and everything else.
The old mail address is too long, so I made a new account with a shorter address.

Now I tell people my new, short email address.
I can check email forwarded from the new account using my old account(delegation).

But if someone were to invite me into a chat using my new account, how will I get notified and chat with that person, using my old account, as the new account without revealing the old account ?

How do I chat on behalf of another gmail account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time isn't possible to chat  "on behalf" of a Gmail address but the users could have a chat session open for each of their Gmail addresses at the same time.

## Alternatives

There are several ways to have several Google chat session open at the same time:

- Use several devices.
- Use different browsers.
- Use several browser profiles, one for each Gmail addresses.
- Use Google multiple sign-in.
- Add all the Gmail addresses to their Android devices.

## References

- [Google Chat Help](https://support.google.com/chat/)
- [Google Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/)
- [Sign in to multiple accounts at once - Google Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en)